# How can I view a django site running with 'runserver' remotely

Tags: django

I currently have a django project that I am working on. The project is sitting on my remote webserver, and I start it by running `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Howver, if I try to access the site via domainname.com:8000, I can't see the site.

How can I view a django project remotely like this? Do I need to do setup using apache? Punch a hole in the firewall? Is there an easy way?

This is strictly for development purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind it to an IP, not `0.0.0.0`.

Also, you may want to check that firewall rules are not stopping you from accessing port 8000 (I did this this morning!)

Comment: Didn't even think of that! Thanks :)

Comment: Wrong. 0.0.0.0 binds on all IPs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ssh tunnels. It's easy to set up in Windows with Putty (look at this [example for manageing postgresql](http://library.linode.com/databases/postgresql/pgadmin-windows)) or google how to use tunnels with ssh in Linux. I think this is amazing thing, since I first time get to my databse on remote server :)

Comment: I would have selected this answer, but the other one is simply more direct. Thanks though :)